# Kinetic / Inertia scrolling in Mac device, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, macos, scroll

I needed fullPageScroller with sections.

I use [FullPageScrollPureJS](https://www.cssscript.com/cross-platform-smooth-one-page-scrolling-pure-javascript/) and is great. Simple to use and modify, but there is problem with Kinetic / Inertia scrolling on mac device.

When you scroll via Touch Bar or Magic Mouse, it will trigger more times (depends on how much user scrolled) and activate animateFunction more than once at a time-

I tried to stop it with time difference counting.

When user scrolled within last 3s, he can't scroll (function that return false before do next stuff).

Which should have stop scrolling more than 1 section at a time (not good solution. rather quick try). But didn't work ...

[Live sample](https://mares-pavel.cz/baterie/index)

Expected result should be - when user on Mac device (with Touch Bar or Magic Mouse) scrolls, the page would scroll only 1 section at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use [Lethargy](https://github.com/d4nyll/lethargy) library. Then integrate it to FullPageScrollPureJS library when try to scroll.